# Como selecionar mais de uma pergunta para colocar na lista de duplicatas?

Tags: suporte

Como posso adicionar mais de uma pergunta à lista das duplicatas?

Quando vou fechar uma pergunta, selecionando o motivo de estar duplicata, o site me dá um prompt para eu colocar o link de **uma** pergunta que poderia responder à questão. No entanto, esse prompt só me permite digitar uma pergunta.

Como faço para adicionar mais de uma pergunta na lista de duplicatas?

Algo assim:

[image: Exemplo...]

A segunda pergunta da lista foi adicionada por alguma das outras pessoas que votou para fechar a pergunta. Até agora, não sei como expandir essa lista no momento  em que estou fechando a pergunta...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O privilégio para editar a lista de duplicatas é o mesmo para fechar e abrir perguntas, que é ter medalha de ouro em alguma das tags do post.

O quadro passa a ter esta opção:

> [image: Screenshot do quadro com link "editar"]

Comment: Que, para esclarecer melhor, primeiro a pergunta é fechada apenas com uma opção de duplicata, mas podendo, através do Editar, adicionar outras 4 perguntas.

Comment: @Woss uma ou mais, depende dos votos antes. Se vc votar dup de A, outro dup de B, e um mod fechar como dup de C, ja começa com ABC na lista.

Comment: essa eu não sabia... achava que era fechada originalmente com a que o mod selecionou e as outras seriam adicionadas manualmente.